# Can't find how to edit HTML code stored in `views_display` table by theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

We are using the WowMag theme from ThemeForest for a new website. A problem we are running into is there is some HTML code stored in the `display_options` column of the `views_display` table that needs to be modified - however, we can't seem to find a way to access this code and modify it from the Drupal admin.

Example here: https://pastebin.com/8RXpMz3s

You can see the code near the bottom - it appears to have something to do with Semantic Views but we aren't sure.

Comment: It looks like you are rewriting the output of the body field into the views itself. You need to look into the fields section of views and need to check the rewriting output section. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Use theme developer to find out what template file is writing that out. Add temporary some extra (debug) output to it on every few lines to find out what line exactly is printing this, to locate problem more precisely.